# if else inside for loop android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, for-loop

This could be worse question but nothing seems to work for me , I have a database in Parse.com like this (created by someone else) :

[image]

now I have to put some validation :

if user's city and user's state match with the db's values the cost will be 30

if user's state matches but not the city the cost will be 50
else the cost will be 100

I write this code :

```
if (ClientList.size() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ClientList.size(); i++) {
        final ParseObject p = ClientList.get(i);
        String state = p.getString("State");
        String city = p.getString("City");
        float cost = Float.parseFloat(p.getString("CostInPrecentage"));
        if(stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
            shippingCost = cost;
        } else if(stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && !cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
            shippingCost = cost;
        } else {
            shippingCost = cost;
        }
    }
}
```

This always returns me shipping cost = 100

I tried to change if else

```
if(stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
    if(cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
        shippingCost = cost;
    } else {
        shippingCost = cost;
    }
} else {
    shippingCost = cost;
}
```

This also returns me shipping cost = 100

if I do soemthig like this :

```
if(stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
    shippingCost = cost;
    break;
} else if(stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && !cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
    shippingCost = cost;
    break;
} else {
    shippingCost = cost;
}
```

It works for default and state but not i case of matching state and city both.

Apart from these I tried many conditions with break also nothing seems to work perfectly .
Could you please suggest how to validate this.

Finally I managed the conditions like this :

```
 if (stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state)&&cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
                                      shippingCost = cost;
                                      break;
                                      }
                                      else if (stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && ((city == null || city =="" || "Default".equalsIgnoreCase(city)))) {

                                     shippingCost = cost;   
                                     break;
                                      }
                                       else if("Default".equalsIgnoreCase(city) && "Default".equalsIgnoreCase(state)){

                                         shippingCost = cost; 
                                         break;
                                      }
```

Comment: your condition is correct. make sure values are correct to do so put a break point and check the values.

Comment: Have you tried adding  `break` in first two `if-else` condition ?

Comment: yes , i tried with break that also not working properly

Comment: Where's your shippingCost  variable ? Inside of for or ?

Comment: no that is a class variable outside the loop , i tried variable inside the loop too ..

Comment: Then it's wrong, you are changing shippingCost in your for loop everytime. Do you want a shipping cost for every client ?

Comment: I want one value after all validation , according to the user's city and state

Comment: But you are iterating all your clients, with variable ClientList and then you are getting only one value after all of your clients ?

Comment: you are getting `cost = 100` because `state` and `city` for last record is matching i.e 'Default` so it will be always 100.

Comment: @SercanOzdemir clientSize =3 , it gives me row values from parse.com

Comment: @Rustam : yes but I dnt want that , that only I want to fix

Comment: replace 1st condition with `if(stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city) &&  (!stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase("Default")&& !cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase("Default")) )`

Comment: still not working for same ( state & city )

Comment: instead of `stateDeli` and `cityDeli` check `sate` and `city` should not be `Default` as `if(stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city) && (!state.equalsIgnoreCase("Default")&& !city.equalsIgnoreCase("Default")) )`

Answer (score -1):

If your after the lowest shipping cost then you will need to ensure a higher shipping cost will not override a lower shipping cost.

```
if (ClientList.size() > 0) {
  for (int i = 0; i < ClientList.size(); i++) {
    final   ParseObject p = ClientList.get(i);
    String state = p.getString("State");
    String city = p.getString("City");
    float cost = Float.parseFloat(p.getString("CostInPrecentage"));

    //if (cost < shippingCost) { // There could be an improvement, otherwise don't try!
      if (stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
        shippingCost = cost;
        break;
      }
      else if (stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && !cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
        shippingCost = cost;
        break;
      }
      else if (!stateDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(state) && !cityDeli.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
        shippingCost = cost;
        break;
      }
    //}
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Answer has been updated to use breaks.

Comment: actually i want the respective value , it could be anything min max or any value .. so this concept will not work

Comment: So as soon as `shippingCost` is set to a meaningful value; then return this value?

Comment: I tried that with break , check my edit .. that works for same state and default value but not for matching (state & city both)